# How to add up the numerical representation of each character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to get the sum of the numerical representations of each character in the name after the ord() function converts the input to integers. I'm new to python so hopefully, I used the correct wording.

```
lastname = input("Enter your lastname: ")
for x in lastname:
print ("The Unicode code point of",x ,'=' ,ord(str(x)))
```

Comment: Hi @HiTower, you can use sum builtin to calculate the sum, check my answer below

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the elements and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) up the ord values

```
#Iterate over characters, and sum up the ords
result = sum(ord(x) for x in lastname)
print(result)
```

Or a traditional for-loop

```
result = 0
for x in lastname:
    result += ord(x)
print(result)
```